# Immutable state update. Update an array of objects in Redux

Tags: redux, immutability, spread-syntax

I have a state of type array that initially looks like that:

```
const initialState = {
    spots: []
}
```

On the first update it gets filled with objects and looks like that:

```
state.spots = [
    { id: '1', available: 1, path: 'xxx' },
    { id: '2', available: 1, path: 'xxz' },
    { id: '3', available: 1, path: 'xxy' },
    { id: '4', available: 1, path: 'bxy' },
    { id: '5', available: 1, path: 'vxy' },
    { id: '6', available: 1, path: 'fxy' }
]
```

On all subsequent updates we get all the spots with keys of 'id' and 'available' but not the path.

So the payload looks like this:

```
payload = [
    { id: '1', available: 1 },
    { id: '2', available: 0 },
    { id: '3', available: 0 },
    { id: '4', available: 1 },
    { id: '5', available: 0 },
    { id: '6', available: 1 }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out the immutable ES6 pattern to update the state but I cannot seem to get it right.

EDIT:
Best solution I have found so far is the following:

```
state.spots = state.spots.map( (spot, key) => {    
  let new_spot = payload.find(o => o.id === spot.id);
  return { ...spot, ...new_spot }
})
```

What is the most efficient way to properly update all objects of the array "spots" with the new payload.

Hope it is clear.
Thanks

Comment: Seems like it would be easier if the payload and state were objects with id as key and the rest as value. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-voice-e4lux)

---

You can create a hash map of your payload using each spot's id as the key:

```
const payload = [
    { id: '1', available: 1 },
    { id: '2', available: 0 },
    { id: '3', available: 0 },
    { id: '4', available: 1 },
    { id: '5', available: 0 },
    { id: '6', available: 1 }
]

// You can adjust the map to how you like.

const map = payload.reduce((acc, entry) => {
    acc[entry.id] = entry
    return acc
}, {})
```

and then update `state.spots` in your reducer:

```
return {
    ...state,

    spots: state.spots.map(e => {
        if (map[e.id]) return { ...e, ...map[e.id] };
        return e;
    })
};
```